# Get a source code from URL web page with JavaScript using JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, jsonp

I'm trying to get the source code form a URL web page using JSONP.
This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var your_url = '';

$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.ajax = (function(_ajax){

var protocol = location.protocol,
    hostname = location.hostname,
    exRegex = RegExp(protocol + '//' + hostname),
    YQL = 'http' + (/^https/.test(protocol)?'s':'') + '://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?',
    query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"';

function isExternal(url) {
    return !exRegex.test(url) && /:\/\//.test(url);
}

return function(o) {

    var url = o.url;

    if ( /get/i.test(o.type) && !/json/i.test(o.dataType) && isExternal(url) ) {
        // Manipulate options so that JSONP-x request is made to YQL

        o.url = YQL;
        o.dataType = 'json';

        o.data = {
            q: query.replace(
                '{URL}',
                url + (o.data ?
                    (/\?/.test(url) ? '&' : '?') + jQuery.param(o.data)
                : '')
            ),
            format: 'xml'
        };

        // Since it's a JSONP request
        // complete === success
        if (!o.success && o.complete) {
            o.success = o.complete;
            delete o.complete;
        }

        o.success = (function(_success){
            return function(data) {

                if (_success) {
                    // Fake XHR callback.
                    _success.call(this, {
                        responseText: data.results[0]
                            // YQL screws with <script>s
                            // Get rid of them
                            .replace(/<script[^>]+?\/>|<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi, '')
                    }, 'success');
                }

            };
        })(o.success);

    }

    return _ajax.apply(this, arguments);

};

})(jQuery.ajax);

$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
         var text = res.responseText;
         //document.getElementById("contenuto").innerHTML = text;

    alert(text);
}
});


});
</script>
```

I printed with an alert all the source code, from the URL.

```
alert(text);
```

First, how to know if the printed code is all the web code of the page?
If I try to do in this way

```
document.getElementById("contenuto").innerHTML = text;
```

this is the result:

```
\ \ <'+'/ins>\ \ \ '); } ]]>
```

I tried to use HTML DOM to print just one element, doing in this way

```
 document.getElementById("contenuto").innerHTML = text;
 var elem = text.getElementById("strip_adv").innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("contenuto_1").innerHTML = elem;

}
```

But this is the error on the JS console:

```
text.getElementById is not a function
```

Recap:
I would to get the source code of a web page from URL, using JSONP.
I would use HTML DOM from the returned text, to keep only the element/class I need. I'm a newbie on JS, I'm trying to learn more & more about JS.

Comment: `responsetext` is not an element. You should try to parse it.

Comment: @mok If i tried to print using this code

    document.getElementById("contenuto").innerHTML = text;

This is the result is: [screen1] (https://postimg.org/image/erjvgz9s7/)
Why? First, I would print the whole "string" (source code of the page), to check if it's complete. But I can't.

Comment: Seems your code is not parsing the page properly. Try it with a simple page like this [http://www.murgaboots.com/aboutus.html] (Selected randomly just as a simple webpage). Anyway, the answer is what I said before, you should parse the `responsetext`.

Comment: I have tried using that page. The result is a page without some CSS style, but It's a HTML page, I would see the source code, with tag ecc!

Answer (score 0):

getElementById() is present only in the document object. What you are trying to do is trying to access getElementId from a string object.

Instead what I would suggest is insert the returned html string inside iframe and you can access the elements within iframe **otherwise** you can use some kind of html parser in your application.

lets say your html looks like this after you insert your html string inside iframe

```
<body>
    <iframe id="one">
      <html>
        <body> <h1 id="strip_adv">Heading</h1> </body>
      </html
    </iframe>
</body>

function iframeObj( frameEle ) {
    return frameEle.contentWindow
        ? frameEle.contentWindow.document
        : frameEle.contentDocument
}

var element = iframeObj( document.getElementById('strip_adv') );
```

Comment: This is what happens doing like you told me.
[screen1](https://postimg.org/image/rqb5gvzaf/)

After 1-2sec
[screen2](https://postimg.org/image/erjvgz9s7/)

Comment: Im sorry I couldn't make out anything from those images. Can you try creating a jsfiddle? It would be easy to help in that way

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1opcanpg/1/). It's the first time that I use jsfiddle...